# How do I emit a call to [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(char)?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I am currently emitting a call to `[mscorlib]System.Console::Write(char)` as follows:

```
ilg.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call,
             typeof(Console).GetMethods().First(m =>
                 m.Name == "Write" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
                 m.GetParameters().Any(p => p.ParameterType == typeof(char))),
             null);
```

But is there a **cleaner way** on how I can reference the `Console.Write(char)` method, possibly without actually iterating through the formal arguments?

Comment: Side notes: I see nothing particularly wrong about the way it is written (assuming it is cached if measurements show benefits of caching). You may drop `Any` as `m.GetParameters()[0]== typeof(char)` to make it shorter...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [`GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1.aspx), rather than `GetMethods`:

```
ilg.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, 
  typeof(Console).GetMethod("Write", new[] { typeof(char) }),
  null);
```

Comment: +1 Looks much better.  But I edited your answer to add the third actual argument to the method since there is no overload for `EmitCall` which takes two arguments.